# How do I stop flask_socketio setting SO_REUSEPORT?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio, python-socketio

If I do this, then port 8080 will be exclusively bound and trying to run another instance will fail:

```py
from flask import Flask

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
flask_app.run(port=8080)
```

If I do this, then the `SO_REUSEPORT` socket option is set, which means multiple instances can be started all using port 8080:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
sio = SocketIO(flask_app)
sio.run(app=flask_app, port=8080)
```

This `SO_REUSEPORT` socket option behaviour is really rather undesirable for my use case. Anyone know how I can stop this?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into it, and, `eventlet.listen` does have an undocumented `reuse_port` parameter.

The `flask_socketio` maintainer doesn't want to support server specific options for the `SocketIO.run` call though, so the solution can only be to run the server without `SocketIO.run`. An eventlet specific replacement for the `sio.run(app=flask_app, port=8080)` without SSL and error handling, but with the `reuse_port` parameter that I require, would be:

```py
    addresses = eventlet.green.socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1', 8080)

    sock = eventlet.listen(
        addresses[0][4],
        addresses[0][0],
        reuse_port=False,
    )

    eventlet.wsgi.server(sock, flask_app)
```